# Differential equation with the Dirac Delta as the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm wondering if there exists a differential equation with that dirac delta as the solution. I can think of plenty of integral equations such that that's true,  but I can't think of any differential equations.

This question occurred to me because I was thinking about Lax equivalence (using finite differencing) in that if we have a numerical scheme that would capture such a solution, it cannot possible be stable, and thus blurring the definition of what it means to converge.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about linear ODEs with smooth coefficients, I guess? In that case I think that more or less any example that you can craft will be trivial: that is, either you need a distributional input (such as in E.T.'s answer), or you need to rely on some other triviality (for example, the equation $x^2 u' = 0$ as $\delta$ as its solution).

Comment: $$x\cdot u' = -u$$

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{{\rm d}{\rm y}\left(x\right) \over {\rm d}x} = \delta'\left(x\right)}$

Comment: Then I guess my followup question would be how would one solve a differential equation involving a distribution numerically? Or is that just non-sense?

Comment: It is not non-sense. You can always approximate a distribution with a function: for instance, a sharp peak approximates a Dirac delta, while a couple of opposed sharp peaks approximates a derivative of the Dirac delta, and so on. You can solve numerically the equations involving those approximations of distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it satisfies the differential equation 
$$\frac{df}{dx}+E=0$$
in the distributional sense, where the distribution $E$ is defined by $E(\phi):=\phi'(0)$.